# Gmail duplicates outgoing emails

Tags: gmail, apple-mail

Help me please. I've been used OSX native Mail client and noticed an issue (you can see it on image below).

As you can see - each sent email duplicates more times. What is that? I suppose that it's an Mail client bug, or Gmail incorrect options... or so on. What is that exactly? How can I fix it?

[image: gmail bug]

Comment: Is your `Sent` folder in Apple Mail configured to use Gmail's `Sent` folder? Don't use Apple Mail anymore, but you should be able to select the Gmail Sent folder and in the menu bar, *Mailbox » Use this Mailbox for » Sent*

Comment: I don't configure anything. How can I do it.

Comment: Well, as I said. Maybe post a screenshot of your Mail mailboxes, especially under the `[Gmail]` domain. I assume you're using IMAP?

Comment: Here is my properties: https://skitch.com/invis89/8h33m/screen-shot-2012-05-26-at-4.00.12-pm
And yes, it's IMAP.